# Web development : how to make button click event download a file using html + jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-click-event

I need to create an  html script that create a table of contact and using the jQuery. I am trying to download this html page and convert it to excel file.

can anyone help me ??

I have this html file

## contact.html

```
<div id="dv">
  <table id="tblExport" style="border:1px solid black; ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style='background-color:red;'>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="btnExport">Export to excel</button>
</div>

</div>
```

So how to use jQuery to make  the button download this table and convert it 
 to an excel sheet ??

Answer (score 0):

Use the data:application property:

```
$("#Export").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dv').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Open the downloaded file with Excel.

http://jsfiddle.net/eozwh49u/

Comment: i am trying to use your code but it did not download anything so what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: try using chrome or firefox it downloads the file

Comment: actually i am using Firefox  and chrome but now action happen when i click on the button

Comment: This code has an incorrect button selector of `#Export` compared to the OP html of `btnExport`

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery `on` event over the `click`. Because if you are loading your form via ajax then `click` will not work. Then you can use simple `html` function on your `div` to get the html content and pass it to excel

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnExport", function () {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dv').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a click handler on the button and then export the div

```
$("#btnExport").on("click", function() {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dv').html());
});
```

NOW IF you want, you can trigger this from code:

```
$("#btnExport").trigger('click');
```